# How to pass efficiently a huge sized parameter to a function?

Tags: python-3.x, security, networking, out-of-memory, knockd

thank you reading. Please forgive my English, I'm french. *Is it a justification ?*

The aim of my function is to scan many IPv4:PORT via multi*processing/threading* (*do not, I forsee you, do not !*) in Python3, send a SYN and register any result. Multisomething is called here because of the timeout needed to wait to any potential reply.
So.

This function is called a **producer**. It stores potential TCP connection into a database. **Consumers**
 then read the database and do some pentesting indepently. So.

I prepared an IPv4 list. It's a random valid IP list of 10's K elements. Remember we have 65K ports to test per IPv4.

My method is then to suffle the list port with a new seed for each producer launched. I have many. Each have a valid IPv4 list, but, if we consider 65K ports with 100K IP's, we have a 6.5G elements to pass.

Why ?

`IP[]` are `random.shuffle()`*-like*, by construction. `Ports[]` are too.

If I read `p in Ports` and for each `p`, join `IPv4:Ports` and append into `params[]`, I can launch the *parallelized* job via `scan(u) for u in params[]`

I launch it via `run(rounds)` like this :

```
def run(rounds):
   for r in rounds:
      scan(r)
```

But, the problem is `size(rounds)` = `size(params)` *~ 6.5G elements*

I cannot find a efficient (*memory talking*) way to pass such a huge parameter (big list) to a parallelized job. I'm running out of memory.

I'm not asking how to manage it on a mind-blowing-capable workstation, while having designed this function on a paper, it doesn't fit into the raspi2 (**1GB mem**).

I do not need Python3 at all for myself, it a teaching product. Thus, i'm stuck.

My question is : could you help me to find a efficient way to attack a huge list by a parallelized function that pop's the list without sending it via a parameter ?

I googled, followed forums and threads I'm aware of, but, as I refactor the programm, the constant problem stays, laughing at me, at the same place in the *main()*.

What I dont want to reproduce :

```
MAX_IPV4 = i.IPv4Address._ALL_ONES
MAX_PORT = 65535

def r_ipv4():
    while True:
        a=i.IPv4Address._string_from_ip_int(r.randint(0, MAX_IPV4))
        b=i.IPv4Address(a)
        if b.is_multicast or b.is_private or b.is_loopback or b.is_reserved or b.is_link_local :
            continue
        else :
            return a
            break

def generate_target():
    return r_ipv4()

def generate_r_targets(n):
    ip=[]
    for i in range(0,n):
            ip.append(generate_target())
    ports=[]
    for p in range(1,65535):                                                                         
            ports.append(p)
    r.shuffle(ports)
    targets=[]
    for p in ports:
        for z in ip:
            targets.append((str(z)+","+str(p)))
```

It's not my optimal method, but the way I can explain and show the problem at best.

I dont want to lost the (shuffled ports) iterable, it is my principal vector and it is at the heart.
I'm testing a dynamic configuration of knockd.

Say. Computer_one register a sequence in knockd.
Computer_one is the only one to know the seed.
The seed is the key of the sequence of keys of knockd, that's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We passed it via a plain file :)